# Endpoint questions with CloudFront & S3

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am creating an iOS app with S3 currently without distributions (CloudFront) as a test before I divulge into creating a full pledged app. In the S3 Management Console, I have made my bucket in Singapore, where I live, so CloudFront isn't really needed for this demo. I have to set an endpoint like this:

```
[s3Client setEndpoint: [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint: AP_SOUTHEAST_1]];
```

Which points to Singapore, endpoint is the place the bucket needs to send the data off to right? (Where the user is)

So now I have two questions

- If I am using CloudFront, do I need to set an endpoint? How do I even use CloudFront in iOS, I generate a signed URL then what?
- If a user is using the app in a random country lets say, what endpoint, if I need to set (with CloudFront), would I set it to? Would I find their current country via the locale and find which endpoint it is closest to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A set of files in CloudFront is called a "distribution."  When you set up a distribution, you specify one or more "origins", which is/are the canonical source of the files you're serving to your users.

In your case, create a new distribution and specify the S3 bucket as the origin.  Then in your application, you'd reference it as: `http://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/hello.png` rather than `http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/hello.png`.  Cloudfront will automatically fetch `hello.png` from the S3 bucket the first time someone requests it and cache it.

CloudFront automatically (and near-instantaneously) detects which edge location is closest to the user by routing them based on network latency.  You don't have to do any of these calculations yourself.

I'd recommend that you [read the caveats that I've listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855853/statics-deployment-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-and-aws-cloudfront/13871011#13871011) though before using CloudFront in your app.

Comment: But what would I set the endpoint to? Right now I HAVE to set my Amazon S3 client's endpoint otherwise it crashes.             
I never actually use the link provided, I send requests to the bucket names with a client... but what I am uploading is data representation of a dictionary, which isn't possible to access and download through a link. How would I implement this link, this url reference shouldn't work in a browser, thats easy access to private property, you generate a signed URL. I tried that on the FireFox S3 Manager (Manage Distributions) but the URL doesnt work in Safari.

Comment: It says: SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

I can try generating a URL in my own code however.... and see if that works. But again how do I implement the CloudFront signed link? Is there a doc/sample (AWS usually has those) you can point me to? I havent managed to find one showing how to do it...

Comment: Can you check out my newer questions on CloudFront, its a problem Im having and maybe you can help... thanks!

Comment: I am facing issue to fetch image(private content) from amazon Cloud front in iOS app. I have no idea , How to fetch image/ file from cloud front in iOS . Please suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jamieb. You should create a new Cloudfront distribution and set the S3 bucket as the origin. Then, you will no longer use the s3 bucket link, you will now use the cloudfront link to view the image. Cloudfront will pull image from S3 and store it as a cache for however long you determine. For example, if the image is going to be looked at constantly by different people in the same region, you are going to want it cached in the edge location in that region, so when a new user in that region looks it up,  they get the image much more quickly.

Comment: Hi @Anantsan,  Welcome to SO! Please consider this writing as part of the comment